# How to Integrate angular cli project with nodejs/expressjs project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, angular-cli, mean-stack

I have 2 projects, as shown in the following images.
The **Node, and Express project** is in the `root` folder, and the **Angular CLI project** inside of `angular-src` folder.
I can run each project individually, back-end on port 3000 with `node app.js` and front-end on port 4200 with `ng serve`
What is the best way to integrate both projects, and the easiest in deployment?

[Full Project Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBLay.png)
[Full Project Folder with angular src files shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3lnW.png)

Comment: When you say integrate, do you mean you want to serve up the angular application from your node webserver?

Comment: @Garuuk yess, I mean running both applications on the same port for example, or rendering the angular project when requesting with GET from my node project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most people keep their frontend (fe) and backend (be) in separate repos. This makes sense when you think that you can have multiple fe's for a single be.

However, its often easier just to keep them in the same repo. Then when you deploy you only need to clone one repo.

Also, it depends what route you do down. Will you installed Node.js etc on your server or will you go down the docker route?

People often like to use docker to containerise their fe and be. The benefit of this approach is that you only need one dependency installed on each server you deploy too, that is docker itself. Everything else exists in the docker world.

Also, docker makes it easy to docker pull from any server. If things go wrong, just kill your docker container and spin up a new one (assuming your data would not be lost in doing so, not a worry for the fe but a be concern).

Obviously, there is the docker learning curve but it's not too painful.